# Should I use enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or enctype='multipart/form-data' for sending both upload files and text using AJAX in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, ajax, upload, multer, enctype

This is the form html code. I am using `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` currently.

```
  <form  name="{{this.status}}" class="commonForm" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/api/upload/{{this.commonID}}" method="post">
<td>
      <input type="file" id="{{this._id}}" class="form-control" name="FileUploadForClient" multiple required {{this.statusDisabled}} />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block col-sm-2" style="font-size:16px" {{this.statusDisabled}}>Submit</button>
</td>
</form>
```

MY AJAX call:

```
 var formData = new FormData(this);
    formData.append('text',"Awesome Font!");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            if (response.status == '200') {

        $.LoadingOverlay("hide");

        swal({
        title: "Excellent!",
        text: "Files submitted successfully!",
        icon: "success",
        button: "Ok",
        showCancelButton: true
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result) {
            window.location.reload();
        }
      });
```

I want to send the text field which I have appended above along with the files uploaded.
Files are submitted successfully but when i try to use `req.body.text` in `nodejs` it gives undefined. WHy?????????????

Here is the route code:

```
router.post('/api/upload/:cid',function(req,res,next){
console.log("yes it came under api");

console.log("req.body.text = " + req.body.text + req.query.text);

      upload2(req,res,function(err) {
          if(err) {
            console.log("Error is important = "+ err);
          }
          else
          {
            console.log("Uploaded");

}
})
})
```

So my main problem is: How to access the text field on server side in `nodejs` after sending via `AJAX` with `FormData`??? Pls help!!!

Comment: Formdata parses your request data as a multipart form and you need to parse the form in express using middleware. There is no need to use formdata unless you are sending different types of data ie. images, audio etc. Just directly set data in your ajax call to an object.

Comment: Then how to parse the FormData in express using middleware? And I already mentioned that I want to send pdfs, jpgs, pngs files as well along with json datas.

Comment: [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) is a good multipart form middleware for express